# WooCommerce / Elementor change Add To Cart button text and link for variable products

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to edit the 'add to cart' button on WooCommerce and I'm using Elementor products widget to show them on shop page and other category pages.

I need to change the button text to 'Quick Add' for simple and variable products and also edit the  link to automatically add the default product to the cart for variable products (instead of having the 'select options' button) and trigger the side cart.

Is there a php filter I can use to change text and href link on specific pages?

Thanks!